# Entity Framework 4 goes back to the database when executing the same query twice

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework

I always assumed that EF caches query results and that it would just return a list of entities from it's internal cache, instead of executing the same query twice on the database.

```
var cipEntities = new CIPEntities(); // instantiate objectcontext
Console.WriteLine(cipEntities.Customers.ToList()); // fires db query
Console.WriteLine(cipEntities.Customers.ToList()); // also fires db query
```

Do I have the wrong assumption? Could it be that I am confused by my experience with RIA services, maybe RIA services does cache results and EF does not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your assumption is wrong. EF doesn't have second level cache (caching querires) so when you execute the query EF doesn't know that it is a query already executed on the same context and it executes the query again. The main rule in EF - query is always executed even the result is already tracked by the context (and can be extracted from the context).

The solution is caching provider mentioned by @Robotsushi.

Answer (score 3):

You can store the resulting list of objects in a static list and query it all you like without returning to the database.

If you want to tweak caching you can check out : [Tracing and Caching Providers](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4747)

If you're going to be querying by id though, you can use the ObjectContext.GetObjectByKey method, and it will look in the object cache before querying the db.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behaviour with the EF, an easy way around this is to cache your results to a local variable and use this instead:

```
var results = cipEntities.Customers.ToList();
Console.WriteLine(results);
Console.WriteLine(results);
```

Comment: @Chad: That's why he saves the result in a local list.

Comment: @Chad - I think you missed the point here. You cache it to a local list (see the call to `ToList()` on the query) so there is no need to call `ToList()` again.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you choose to cast it as a preenumerated class (i.e. `.ToList()`) then EF will execute the query each time you seek to enumerate.  In fact if you use a complex class as a stored procedure result unless you cast it using an enumerated collection it will throw an error.